# Stripe returning same token again

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am using `stripe` to manage my transactions.

I have a need to add the customer (if not already present) and then add the card to that customer.

Now i have to get token for both processes which i did by

```
stripe.tokens.create({
    card: {
        "number": "4242424242424242",
        "exp_month": "1",
        "exp_year": "2019",
        "cvc": "123"
    }
}, function (err, token) {
    // asynchronously called
    if (token != null) {
        //Do something
    }
    else {
         //Do something
    }
});
```

Now i am calling this method twice to get new token every time to add customer if not present and to add card to that customer. But every time i get same response as i am sending same information of the card.

```
    1St

{
  "id": "tok_16v4mvBR7e7FUB557PD3hOZc",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_16v4mvBR7e7FUB55KD06kqJo", 
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Diners Club",
    "country": null,
    "cvc_check": "unchecked",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 10,
    "exp_year": 2021,
    "fingerprint": "iE2uiiDxUFHRgpt1",
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "5904",
    "metadata": {},
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "client_ip": "51.25.52.52",
  "created": 1444650501,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}

2nd
{
  "id": "tok_16v4mvBR7e7FUB557PD3hOZc",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_16v4mvBR7e7FUB55KD06kqJo",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Diners Club",
    "country": null,
    "cvc_check": "unchecked",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 10,
    "exp_year": 2021,
    "fingerprint": "iE2uiiDxUFHRgpt1",
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "5904",
    "metadata": {},
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "client_ip": "55.55.55.55",
  "created": 1444650501,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

Check every field is same as first.

But if i want to use the same token which i get first time i am getting error

```
Stripe Error 400 - Cannot use stripe token more than once
```

So my question is if i am getting the same token again then why it is giving me error in using the token returned first time for adding customer and to add card for that customer.

This could increase my site speed if i do not have to get token again.

Comment: Sending the same card info will not generate the same token. What do you do with the token once you obtain it? What line actually throws the error?

Comment: It is generating the same token again i put the response above. The token i get i use it for two purposes First to save customer and then to save card for that customer.

The error is when i tried to send the request to Stripe using same token again for creating the credit card.

Comment: when you save customer it automatically creates a card, saving a card again would cause the customer to have two of the same cards

Comment: ok but let me explain my business process the text won't be formatted. First i ask for filling credit card information from user after that i ask for the token from stripe for the credit card. then i save the customer first if not already present and then again ask for token for same credit card and then i add credit card to the customer . I think i made it pretty clear now

Comment: I don't get why you ask again for a token, if you create the customer with the token you shouldn't need to ask again. You also shouldn't be creating tokens from Node.js as thats not PCI compliant, tokens should be generated client side using Stripe.js

Comment: The process for creating customer and the card both require tokens, so will the token created by Stripe.js would work with stripe?

Comment: And if i do not ask for token again then it gives me error "Stripe Error 400 - Cannot use stripe token more than once" i ask token two times first for creating customer and second to add card  for that customer.

Comment: creating a customer does not require a token a token is optional. Creating a customer with a token is the same as creating a customer without a token and adding the card separately. Creating a customer with a token, and then adding a card to that customer for the same token / card makes no sense.

Comment: Okay what i am getting is that i should create customer without token and then add credit card for that customer by creating token from stripe.js ?

Comment: Can you tell me what this method s doing beacuse i am using this method to get token [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token)

Comment: You don't need to add the card separately is what I'm saying. The api you linked should be used just for testing and not in production for PCI reasons

Comment: answer the question with little more detail it is getting bit messy in comments.

Comment: i got it what you are saying when i add customer it add card for that customer because creating customer requires card information too. but still one question remains how to add card to **existing** customer.

Comment: you'd obtain the token using Stripe.js or Stripe Checkout

Comment: ok if your could add an answer then i would accept it and this will close the question helping other too or should i answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments of @Matthew Arkin

*`I have a need to add the customer (if not already present) and then add the card to that customer.`*

The Business logic of stipe is such that when you ask user for credit card detail only then it will add customer so they are not different but same procedures.

The stripe Token is a way to encode the following things:

1) A bank account

2) A credit card detail

To get a token you should pass Card information for credit card like [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token).

Now you can get the same token using [stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js). the good thing for using stripejs is the a token will be sent instead of a card information.

To add a customer you should supply either the token from stripe.js (or from api) or the card information. using token is what i think is best method.

When you do call stripe using token you automatically create customer with a card. hence customer **cannot** be created without the card information supplied to stripe.

If you want to add card to existing customer then do following:

**1) Retrieve customer passing customer id **

**2) Check customer for null and then add the card for that customer obtaining a token from stripe.js**

Comment: Was getting same issue just need some clarification.So when I create customer it automatically creates a card too? I was creating a customer using stripe_token then saved customer's stripe id in db, now next line creats charge using customer till here fine.But I have a need to create card and store (only) the stripe card id on our db , here this error occurs.